# chmod: cannot access ‘\r’: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have these 2 line in my `aaa.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod +x  /home/tot/*.html
```

When  I run it on AWS EC2 Linux:

```
$ sh aaa.sh
```

I got this message:

```
chmod: cannot access ‘\r’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You have Windows line endings in your file (`\r\n`). It needs to have Unix-style line endings (`\n` only).

Comment: @AndrewMedico suggest that as an answer

Comment: run the file through dos2unix or a similar utility

Comment: Thanks. How to heg rid of \r when I use vi editor on Linux?

Comment: `vi` tends to adapt to line endings; if you're editing a file with Windows-style endings, it might not let you remove them. Quit` vi and fix the file using `dos2unix`. (Be sure to read the man page; unlike most text filters, `dos2unix` replaces its input file rather than writing to `stdout`).

Comment: If you don't have `dos2unix`, you can probably install it; the package name is `dos2unix`. Or you can use `tr`, something like this: `tr -d '\r' < aaa.sh > aaa.sh.$$ && mv aaa.sh.$$ aaa.sh`

Comment: I faced the same issue on my windows machine, resolved it by using the above command. I was trying to resolve this issue for the last two days on windows, though I didn't get any issue on ubuntu. Thanks a lot @KeithThompson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have Windows line endings in your file (\r\n). It needs to have Unix-style line endings (\n only).

You can do the conversion with the common `dos2unix` utility, or the `set ff=unix` command in vim.

Answer (score 0):

chmod shouldn't care about the contents of your files. I bet you have a file with a control character in the filename itself. Might display as a question mark, but `ls -b *.html` should show you the culprit. Are your sure you *want* executable html files?

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but it's more likely that the script itself has Windows-style line endings. Good point about executable HTML files.